# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND in nodejs soap

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I am using following code and I am getting error.

```
var soap = require('soap');

var url = 'http://ws.strikeiron.com/GlobalAddressVerification5?WSDL';

soap.createClient(url, function(err, client){
  console.log(err)
  console.log(client)

});
```

Error:

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ws.strikeiron.com]
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'ws.strikeiron.com' }
undefined
```

I have set the npm proxy & .npmrc has the following entries:

```
proxy=http://localhost:3128/
https-proxy=http://localhost:3128/
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you installed the soap globally using npm install soap -g. If you are using ubuntu try using sudo npm install soap -g

Comment: soap is installed globally as an administrator and I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Can you try with deleting proxy. Try once without proxy.Also try to delete proxy once. Update your soap to the latest version and also update the version of soap to latest in package.json file/configuration file . Try npm config delete proxy also

Comment: did you find any solutions ?

Comment: have you found any solutions for above issue?